# Using request.cookies in routeDataBase Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use cookies on a route database in Django, or is there another way?

**middlewares.py**

```
class DefinedRouteDataBase(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            request.COOKIES['token'] = request.POST['token']
            print ('Middlewares:', str(request.COOKIES['token']))
        return None
```

**RouterDataBases.py**

```
class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    print('Router R:')
    #HERE FAIL :(
    return request.COOKIES['token']

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
     print ('Router W:')
     return 'default'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    return None

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at all. Database routers cannot access the request (they don't receive such data).

The only (and ugly) solution I can think about is using a `threading.local` which you could initialize in your middleware (`DefinedRouteDataBase`):

```
#in mymoduleforthisuglysolution.py
from threading import local

mylocal = local()

#in your middleware definition file
from mymoduleforthisuglysolution import mylocal

class DefinedRouteDataBase(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        #if request.method == 'POST':
        #    request.COOKIES['token'] = request.POST['token']
        #    print ('Middlewares:', str(request.COOKIES['token']))
        mylocal.request = request
        return None

#in your router definition file
from mymoduleforthisuglysolution import mylocal

class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        print('Router R:')
        return mylocal.request.COOKIES['token'] if mylocal.request else 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        print ('Router W:')
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return True
```

This solution is ugly and will not work if you use GEvent (since each request lives in a greenlet instead of a separate thread), but this is the only solution I can think about since there's no a connection path between routers and requests.

One question: Why would you store the database key in the cookie? that would be preety dangerous xD.

Comment: Thanks for the information, what happens is that I require to change the database I will use as the user logging in: (

Comment: I know. But seems to be not possible and it reminds me to components not being able to validate over requests, and I had to perform the same approach (but for a field component instead).

Comment: I will define my idea of applying again, thanks friend